# Warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame -- Using List of Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am getting the following warning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Here is my code that is getting the warning:

```
col_names = ['Column1', 'Column2']
features = X_train[col_names]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)
X_train[col_names] = features
```

I realize this is happening because I'm copying the dataframe. But what I am doing here is not like any of the answers I found googling, so I can't figure out how to apply their answers to my particular situation. It looks like the normal scenario where you get this warning is if you do something like this:
d2 = data[data['name'] == 'fred']

So .loc doesn't work. And .assign doesn't either because I have a list of columns instead of just a column I can assign. I'm just not quite sure how to handle this the way it wants me too.

It works fine the way it is, other than the warning. So the way I have it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the warning is saying for you to do something like

```
X_train.loc[:, col_names] = features
```

Comment: na it's ok, it's kind of a weird behaviour IMO

Comment: The warning also shwos up if you do that. At least for me